# How to allow my C++ code to update variables?

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding and C++.

The code below is meant to monitor a magswitch and a status led on another controller. The code needs to run once the magswitch pin goes high (this works).

The additional code for pulseIn, is what I hope to use to monitor different flash rates of the led when I get the code working. For now I'm just looking for the **state** variable to update with the **if** and **else if** statements.

When I toggle the statusPin, the code picks up the changing state, but I cannot get it to update the **"state"** and **"statuspinstate"** variables.

The statuspinstate variable shows as 1, even though it is initialized as 0.

I inserted all the serial prints to try and see where things are going wrong.

**This is the serial print when "statusPin" is LOW:**

statuspinstate: 0
rate1: 2147483647
period: 0.00
rate2: 0
ontime: 0
offtime: 0
*state: 0*
*statepinstatus: 1*

**This is the serial print when "statusPin" is HIGH**

statuspinstate: 1
rate1: 2147483647
period: 0.00
rate2: 0
ontime: 0
offtime: 0
*state: 0*
*statepinstatus: 1*

Code:

```
    const int statusPin = 19; //Reads status led
    const int magSwitch = 22; //Magswitch to detect movement
    
    int ontime,offtime,rate1,rate2;
    float freq,period;
    volatile unsigned int state =0;
    volatile unsigned int statuspinstate = 0;
       
void setup()
{
pinMode(statusPin, INPUT);     //input from controller
pinMode(magSwitch, INPUT);
Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop()
{
   while (digitalRead(magSwitch) == LOW) {

}


{   

   statuspinstate = digitalRead(statusPin);
   ontime = pulseIn(statusPin,HIGH);
   offtime = pulseIn(statusPin,LOW);
   period = ontime+offtime;
   rate1 = (ontime/period);       //future use
   rate2 = (offtime);             //future use
   Serial.println(String("statuspinstate ") + (digitalRead(statusPin)));   //all serial print is debug info
   Serial.println(String("rate1: ") + (rate1));
   Serial.println(String("period: ") + (period));
   Serial.println(String("rate2: ") + (rate2));
   Serial.println(String("ontime: ") + (ontime));
   Serial.println(String("offtime: ") + (offtime));
   delay(500);
}

   if ((ontime) != 0)
    state = period;

   else if (statuspinstate = 1)
    state = 9999;

   else if (statuspinstate = 0);
    state = 0;
    
   Serial.println(String("state: ") + (state));
   Serial.println(String("statepinstatus: ") + (statuspinstate));

    statuspinstate = 0;                                         //return statuspinstate to zero
   
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of issues with this code. For starters: you probably don't mean to be assining in your conditionals. For example, you probably mean `else if (statuspinstate == 1)`.

Comment: I am honestly very curious, how does one arrive at such an indentation scheme? Please don't take it the wrong way; I genuinely don't get it.

Comment: Try focusing the code on one issue (c.f. [mre]). Pick *one* variable to be concerned about. Remove all the code that is not needed to update that variable. Fix the indentation, test that trimmed down code, and update your question with that code and results instead of the full code and results.

Comment: This is a classic case of a beginner writing too much code with too little testing. Start simple, as simple as you can make it, get the simple code working and then add a little bit more. Repeat until you get to your destination. Don't try and write your whole program in one go.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, that fixed it!

Comment: Nnote that `ontime/period` divides by zero in your case, so formally your entire program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo that is an issue, but if there is pulsing input from the source, the period should no longer be zero.
Do you think pulseIn() would work or should I rather try come up with something to count the amount of times the pin is HIGH during a set period?

Comment: @bitmask, the indentation is better in the compiler, the formatting went out a bit pasting it here.

Comment: @Tigga That's a big "if", and you should still check before dividing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your conditional, with proper indentation (do get a text editor that can indent your code for you):

```
if ((ontime) != 0)
    state = period;
else if (statuspinstate = 1)
    state = 9999;
else if (statuspinstate = 0);
state = 0;
```

We know that `ontime` is zero, so the second condition is tried next.
Now, `statuspinstate = 1` is an assignment, not a comparison, and its value is "truth-y" so you take that branch.
Next, the stray semicolon in `if (statuspinstate = 0);` (which is also an assignment condition, but not evaluated) makes `state = 0` unconditional.

So every time `ontime` is zero, you end up executing `statuspinstate = 1` and `state = 0`.

What you probably want is

```
if (ontime != 0)
    state = period;
else if (statuspinstate == 1)
    state = 9999;
else if (statuspinstate == 0)
    state = 0;
```